# Failed to run Sencha CMD generated ExtJS 6.2 app on Node js

Tags: node.js, express, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am trying to run my existing ExtJS 6.2 app generated using Sencha CMD on Node.js. Below is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app  = express();

//Middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/monitor/' ));
app.post('/', function( req ,res){
    res.send("Success");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});

var server = app.listen(3300, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

However, it is not able to run the page due to the following error.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/build/development/Monitor/classic/resources/Monitor-all_1.css?_dc=1597650810261' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

There is already a guide in [sencha website](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/guides/npm_packages/npm_update.html) but that is not for GPL version of ExtJS. So I cannot update to ExtJS 6.6 or 7.0.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: When you directly load the url in the browser ? wat response do you get ? an html or a css ?? If its an html, you need to fix that

Comment: An html page loads without css. How could I fix it?

Comment: Basically, your static files are rendered from 'public/monitor' folder. So your path `build/development/Monitor/classic/resources/Monitor-all_1.css` should be present with in this folder. If not you have to correct the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because the css file was missing in the folder. I got it from another machine and it fixed the problem.